# How to get second week of Sunday for every month using momentjs

Tags: momentjs

I'm working on the calendar functionality in my project using moment.js, i want to get the date of second week of 'Sunday' for the given month. 
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.day(n)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/), and then just combine it with `.startOf('month')` to do this.

> This method can be used to set the day of the week, with Sunday as 0 and Saturday as 6.
>
> If the value given is from 0 to 6, the resulting date will be within the current (Sunday-to-Saturday) week.
>
> If the range is exceeded, it will bubble up to other weeks.

Demo:

```js
const days = {
    Mon: 1,
    Tue: 2,
    Wed: 3,
    Thu: 4,
    Fri: 5,
    Sat: 6,
    Sun: 7
}
const nthDayOfMonth = (monthMoment, day, weekNumber) => {
  let m = monthMoment.clone()
   .startOf('month')                     // go to the beginning of the month
   .day(day)
  if (m.month() !== monthMoment.month()) m.add(7, 'd');
  return m.add(7 * (weekNumber - 1), 'd').format('dddd YYYY-MM-DD')
}

console.log({
  firstSaturdayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Sat, 1),
  firstSundayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Sun, 1),
  firstMondayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Mon, 1),
  firstTuesdayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Tue, 1),
  firstWednesdayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Wed, 1),
  firstThursdayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Thu, 1),
  firstFridayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Fri, 1),
  secondSaturdayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Sat, 2),
  secondSundayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Sun, 2),
  secondMondayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Mon, 2),
  secondTuesdayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Tue, 2),
  secondWednesdayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Wed, 2),
  secondThursdayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Thu, 2),
  secondFridayThisMonth: nthDayOfMonth(moment(), days.Fri, 2),
  secondTuedayMarch2020: nthDayOfMonth(moment('2020-03-15'), days.Tue, 2),
  thirdFridayDecember1986: nthDayOfMonth(moment('1986-12-04'), days.Fri, 3)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: suppose if i want to get the 1week of Saturday of every month means, what would be the day(number). Is it `.day(6)`? or? some confusion, Could you please explain bit little more.

Comment: see edit - made the snipper more generic so you can see what it's doing hopefully

Comment: Sorry to inform you, suppose if i get 1week of Monday of this month(Feb 2020), the above function give me the wrong date(`Mon Jan 27 2020`), so need to apply logic like if the return date is not a current month need to add `+7`, correct? or Am i wrong?

Comment: No you're right, I didn't realize day would sometimes move the day backwards, fixed it but it's not as pretty unfortunately

Comment: Saved the day!!